# how can guest aosp vm communicate with host BT aosp stack?

Tags: android-source, android-virtual-device, hal, bt

I am running vm cutellfish arm64 on top of another aosp HOST via crosvm .
I would like to enable the feature of bleuttoh as mention in the official google android source like the device trout.
does anyone succeed to make the guest aosp vm perform bt scanning through bt stack of the host aosp ?
https://source.android.com/docs/automotive/virtualization/architecture#bt
[trout bt illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gt7ZC.png)

google does provide any details just an illustration